# Differential equation,bounded solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have some trouble understanding the  proof of a theorem. 
Here is the link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CD6h.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnJnX.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMvPK.png
It is the proof of the theorem 5.1. 
Why would $y$ be unbounded only in the region where $x' <0$? Isn't it possible to have $x'>0$ , so $x$ increasing and $x<K$ and having a limit , while $y$ goes unbounded? Also what does the author mean when he says: "above the maximum height of the curve $f(x,y)=-\alpha$" ? Does he mean that we consider $y$ as a function of $x$, with the condition that $f(x,y) = -\alpha$?

THanks in advance?

Comment: Sorry. Not interested in straining my eyes to decipher a blurry picture. Maybe you could copy the relevant portions using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: i've edited my post with bigger snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

Just some **hints**. 
Firstly, to have $x` >0$ and $x < K$ as $y \to \infty$ represents quite a bizarre prey-predator behaviour. If the prey number approached a constant, one cannot expect the predators to grow unbounded.

As the text you are reading highlights, the expected physical behaviour is achieved by the conditions on the partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$.

We know that $g_x >0 $, $g_y < 0$ and $g(J,0) = 0$ for a certain $J$.

Could you consider how the zeros of $ g(x,y) = 0$ look like, or alternatively, what is the sign of $g(J,y)$? Then it should be clearer why, for $x$ tending to a constant, $g$ must be negative.

If you look at the rest of the proof, where the condition on the partial derivative of $g$ is considered, I believe you will find a formal argument.

In reference to your second point, the equation $f(x,y) = -\alpha$ indeed defined a curve and I believe your interpretation is correct: the maximum height is equivalent to the maximum value of $y$ along the implicitly defined curve $f(x,y) = -\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've drawn the situation and here is what i've got: the curve g(x,y) = 0 is above the x-axis for x greater than J , and g is negative above this curve, and positive below, so x cannot have a constant as a limit. Is this right?

Comment: I am not so sure I follow you. Let me say this. Following the conditions on the partial derivative of $g$, $g(x,y) < 0$ for $x \leq J, y > 0$ (let call this region, upper left quadrant). Also, $g(x,y) > 0$ for $x \geq J, y < 0$ (lower right quadrant). Now $g$ is continous, so there somewhere in between the two "quadrants" must be zero.  Looking a bit at it, one should be able to conclude, if  I am not faulty please verify every word, that whatever constant $x$ is picked, $g$ becomes negative for large enough $y$: not enough preys to feed on....

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had in mind. However, this seems "too" simple whereas the proof in the article is a bit technical. Is there something that I miss? What not have said: consider the maximum height of the curve $g(x,y)=0$ on the  interval $[J, x_{0}]$ if $y$ goes to infinity, then it must be greater than this maximum absurd.

Comment: Well, the proof deals with the other case, i.e. when $x´ < 0$. The simple argument above suffices only to explain why the case $x´ > 0$ is excluded, as done at the beginning of the proof.